# OpenVPN gateway without NAT

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, nat

I'm trying to setup a transparent VPN gateway to a remote network, on the remote network there is an OpenVPN server and on the local network an OpenVPN client acting as gateway.

The diagram shows the IP and routes for each host, in green I have marked the routes I have added to make all work, I want to make NAT on the VPN server, so no additional routes are needed on each server of that network (The server named Destination is an example of a server on that network).

**Edited to add clarification:**

**My problem lives only on the server labeled "VPN client", I can make the setup work by configuring a NAT in that server as described below, but I want it to route packets to "VPN server" without NAT, the NAT will be performed by the "VPN server".**

[image: Connection diagram]

To my understanding a ping from the computer labeled "workstation" to the server labeled "destination" should work but it doesn't, the same ping from the VPN client works as expected with only one NAT performed in the VPN server.

If I open a tcpdump on tun0 at both sides I can see the ping packets from the workstation to the destination on the VPN client, but nothing on the VPN server, here is the output for tcpdump on the VPN client:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 'icmp'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
16:07:11.391614 IP 10.1.110.7 > 192.168.1.63: ICMP echo request, id 10871, seq 49, length 64
16:07:12.404989 IP 10.1.110.7 > 192.168.1.63: ICMP echo request, id 10871, seq 50, length 64
```

**If I add a masquerade rule on the VPN client the ping reaches destination and sends the reply:**

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**But with this setup I would be performing NAT twice, I wan the VPN client to forward the packets without natting.**

The firewall forward policy is set to accept:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And there is no NAT rules which could interfer:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

IP forwaring is enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

**What I am missing?**

Comment: Destination routes packets for `10.1.110.0/24` via `X.X.X.X dev eth0` while your vpn server is on `eth1`. So `route add 10.1.110.0/24 gw 192.168.0.69` on destination.

Comment: @IporSircer I have edited the question to make more clear what my problem really is.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that OpenVPN has it's own routing tables a part from the ones you can see with `ip ro` or `route -n`.

If the OpenVPN server receives a packet from a client with a source address for which it has no routes (the vpn server, not the host) it will drop it before it reaches tun0. When this happens you can see a message like this on the openvpn log:

```
Tue Nov 14 11:26:21 2017 us=135733 client/X.X.X.X:40770 MULTI: bad source address from client [10.1.110.7], packet dropped
```

When this happens you need to add an **iroute**, iroutes are client specific, and you must enable the **client-config-dir**

```
#/etc/openvpn/server.conf
...
client-config-dir ccd
```

Then inside `/etc/openvpn/ccd/<client_name>` you can add your iroute:

```
# /etc/openvpn/ccd/client
iroute 10.1.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

After restarting the OpenVPN server you will start to see your packets reaching tun0 on the other side as this time OpenVPN will not be dropping them.